# Class "Google_Config" not found

Tags: php, google-plus, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to implement Google's login API via the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/aaa_oauth2_web), but for some reason, when I try to run it, I always get:

> Fatal error: Class 'Google_Config' not found in /home/.../Google/Client.php on line 76

I'm quite sure I linked to Client.php correctly - I don't *think* it's a problem within my own code. Does anyone know what might be happening here? Thanks!

Comment: how are you including client.php?

Comment: @raidenace require_once 'Google/Client.php';

Comment: It is not about including `Client.php`. It says it cannot find `Google_Config` class inside `Client.php`. Have you configured classloader properly (assuming you have one)?

Comment: @raidenace Sorry - noob question here. What's a classloader and how do you use one? I found [link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) this, but I'm not exactly sure how do use it.

Comment: @Mt_Xing - in an over-simplistic way, classloader is basically a magic function in php called `__autoload()`- when you instantiate a class in your script, if the class definition file is not included this function is called as a last resort to try and load your class. In your case though,it should not be required-I do not think Google API requires autoloading. Can you check what is your include_path value in php.ini?

Comment: @raidenace get_include_path returns :/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php. I'm also manually running set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '../../PHPDep/Google'); in my code.

Comment: @raidenace Nevermind - I deleted my entire google-api-php-client folder and reuploaded it. It seems to work now. Thanks for your help - if you want the reputation, write an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Mt_Xing: I am glad it worked - thanks for offering to accept an answer from me but I really did not do much to help you here, maybe next time:) I still wonder how just reuploading helped, maybe one those reboot/restart/reupload mysteries in computer science which will never be solved!

Answer (score 4):

This error means that you didn't use Composer, to install the client. 
Without Composer, in your script you should

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) . 'vendor/google-api-php-client/src');  
require_once '/path/to/autoload.php';  
require_once '/path/to/Client.php';
```

Without the autoload.php, no class will be found. In Client.php the code before the Class definition tries to load autoload.php. But you have already found the Client.php, by giving the full path to it. So no loading of autoload.php happens there.

As you say, your problem solved when you reinstalled the API. I suppose you used Composer the second time.

Clarification:
The above note does NOT mean to skip proper client installation, according to [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/installation). Applies for "google/apiclient": "1.0.*@beta"

Comment: The strange thing here is that I didn't use Composer the 2nd time through either... I don't know why; reuploading just magically fixed everything.

Comment: Weird. Why use set_include_path()? Why not just require autoloader then $client = new \Google_Client(); ?

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you downloaded whole release not only master branch from github? You should have /vendors and /src directories - then require /src/autoload.php

Answer (score 1):

google's autoloader doesn't work for me, it's either because of an old version of PHP or a conflict with a competing autoloader, I don't know.

I have even tried manually including googles auto loader (which should be redundant as `src/Google/Client.php` already `require_once`'s the `autoload.php`:

```
require_once 'google-api-php-client/autoload.php'
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/Client.php'
```

`Google_Config` is never found...

ultimatly the only solution is the solution as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/26985116/3338098
i.e.

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/path/to/google-api-php-client/src');
require_once 'Google/Client.php'
```

Answer (score 0):

I fought with this for a while. The reason was actually quite simple:

I had ignored in git "config.php" which ignored this file and that's why it was not in my production environment.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem by following steps

```
> cd "youfolder"
> composer install
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of keeping vendor folder in root folder, keep it in **google-api-php-client-master** folder and use the following line to include it in your project

`require_once DIR.'/google-api-php-client-master/vendor/autoload.php';`