# Google API autoload.php missing

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

I never used the Goodle API before, and now I try to get my feet wet accessing Google calendar via the API.

I downloaded the google-api-php-client-master.zip, extracted the .../src/Google directory and copied it to my webserver (hosted by a 3rd party, which means I can't install anything). According to the samples my code needs to start with

```
<?php
require_once "Google/Client.php";
require_once "Google/Service/Calendar.php";
....
```

but the `Client.php` throws an error:

*Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php5.4') in /homepages/39/d396519017/htdocs/VC2/Google/Client.php on line 18*

Client.php-Line 18 is this line `require_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../autoload.php');`

But I can't fint autoload.php anywhere. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: the autoload.php file is in the base directory not in base/src/Google

Comment: grab v1-master the file is there https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/tree/v1-master

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This is the `autoload.php` file that you're looking for](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/v1-master/src/Google/autoload.php).

It is much better (and easier) to not worry about loading each class file individually and including this `autoload.php` file at the top of the examples that you're going to start working with! Make sure you place the file at the folder that holds the `src` directory.

You could also [follow the installation documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/installation) and set the `src` folder in your include path using:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/path/to/google-api-php-client/src');
```

When doing either of these things, you must instead utilize `use` statements to include the classes that you need.

UPDATE: Google has moved to purely using Composer in its bleeding edge versions [as per this issue](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/716). You should install Composer and run `composer require "google/apiclient:~2.0@dev"` to get the autoload.php file you need, or use a `v1.x.x` tag in the repo. I've updated the autoload.php link to the latest v1 tag.

Comment: @Stefan No problem! If this answer helped you, it would be great for you to check off the grey "checkmark" right below the up/down arrows for this answer.

Comment: Sorry that I missed that...I am new to stackoverflow, still have to find my way around.

Comment: @sjagr simply doing `use` doesn't work. It has to have a namespace in the `use` statement, but I don't know what the namespace for the Google API is

Comment: @mightyspaj3 That was inferred. It's pretty easy with PSR conventions, you just use the folder/file structure in most cases. For OP's example, `use Google\Client;` and `use Google\Service\Calendar;` would both work (notice how that's just like the `require` statements in their question). In the case of the `autoload.php` file that I'm referencing in my answer, that's exactly how the namespace is resolved (through folders).

Comment: The file is missing can some one give me the link to autoload.php file ?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu Updated my answer.

Comment: @sjagr sorry but It is already deprecated, may be something else I need to do. I got `Deprecated: google-api-php-client's autoloader was moved to src/Google/autoload.php in 1.1.3. This redirect will be removed in 1.2. Please adjust your code to use the new location. in E:\work\www\analytica\google-api-php-client\src\Google\autoload.php on line 25`

Comment: Is it only more or does Google leave lots of old and outdated docs around even after releasing new things? You link to https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/installation which suggests using "google/apiclient": "1.0.*@beta" whereas the latest version is 2.+ something.

Comment: @Jonny That's on purpose, as the 2.x versions are only release candidates at the time of my writing of this comment. See the [giant note on the README](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client#note-if-you-arrived-here-from-developersgooglecom-you-should-be-using-the-v1-branch-of-this-repo).