# How to get a refresh token for offline access google analytics access in php

Tags: php, google-analytics, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, analytics

I want to get refresh token for offline access to google analytics using php.I am getting this error:

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Google_Config' not found in /home/vakratu1/public_html/application/googleanalytics4/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Client.php on line 80

Here is my code:

require_once 'google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Client.php';

```
    const REDIRECT_URL = 'http://vakratundasystem.in/application/googleanalytics4/test1.php';
    const CLIENT_ID = '609857927111-8eeiuosueov4ob2fc682u7o4dha52h73.apps.googleusercontent.com';
    const CLIENT_SECRET = 'T7EdzL8oU93kjhyXXkSxduYv';
    const ANALYTICS_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly';

    // Build a new client object to work with authorization.
    //$client = new apiClient();
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId(CLIENT_ID);
    $client->setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET);
    $client->setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URL);
    $client->setScopes(array(ANALYTICS_SCOPE));
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $auth = $client->authenticate();


if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
   $token = $client->getAccessToken();
   $authObj = json_decode($token);
   $refreshToken = $authObj->refresh_token;
}
echo $refreshToken;
```

Comment: you may want to replace your `client_secret` now...

Comment: You should use Composer as outlined in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551826/class-google-config-not-found

Comment: why should we use composer for getting offline access token?

Comment: Well to solve the "class not found error"

Comment: this is my code can you suggest me what to do?[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4B_7bYczMUDUDlORkdpMFdXSXM/view?usp=sharing)